# Is there a way to know if geolocation is enabled for the current domain?

Tags: javascript, w3c-geolocation

The website I'm working on uses HTML5 geolocation api. It works fine, but I need to know if the feature has been authorized.
`navigator.geolocation` only tells if the feature is available. What I want to know is whether the user has enabled it already. Basically, I need to know if the browser will request permission to use the feature. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the user does not allow your app to use the Geolocation API the methods `getCurrentPosition` and `watchPosition` will return an PositionError object via the error callback:

```
void getCurrentPosition(successCallback,
                        errorCallback,
                        options);

long watchPosition(successCallback,
                   errorCallback,
                   options);
```

The PositionError looks like:

```
PositionError {
    code;
    message;
};
```

where the possibles values of code are:

```
PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED = 1;
PositionError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE = 2;
PositionError.TIMEOUT = 3;
```

And more specific:

- PERMISSION_DENIED (numeric value 1)
  The location acquisition process failed because the document does not have permission to use the Geolocation API.

The documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/).

Answer (score 3):

There is no check for permanent authorization.

The only thing you can do imho is try to "guess" if the user has authorized by estimate time.

For example:

- more than 1,5 seconds to retrieve geolocation -> probably user got to
  click interface and give auth
- less than 500ms ->  pretty sure user    already give auth